# Javafx mouse events working, key press events not caught

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I have an existing application that I use to move a 3 d plot of star patterns around (translate, rotate, etc.)

I have the mouse events (press, drag, etc) working fine.

I wanted to added a keyboard event handler, but the odd thing is the it never catches any of the key press events.

I define a subscene to manage things. Here is the event setup and processing code. In the below code, all the mouse events work exactly as expected. No key press events are logged.

```
   private void handleUserEvents() {

        subScene.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent key)-> {
            log.info("key={}", key);
        });

        subScene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
            zoomGraph(deltaY * 5);
            updateLabels();
        });

        subScene.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
                    mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                    mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                    mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
                    mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
                }
        );

        subScene.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) -> {
                    int direction = userControls.isControlSense() ? +1 : -1;
                    mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                    mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                    mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                    mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                    mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
                    mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);
//                    double modifier = 0.2;
                    double modifier = UserControls.NORMAL_SPEED;

                    if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && me.isControlDown()) {
                        log.info("shift sideways");
                        camera.setTranslateX(mousePosX);
                        camera.setTranslateY(mousePosY);
                    } else if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        if (me.isAltDown()) { //roll
                            rotateZ.setAngle(((rotateZ.getAngle() + direction * mouseDeltaX * modifier) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180); // +
                        } else {
                            rotateY.setAngle(((rotateY.getAngle() + direction * mouseDeltaX * modifier) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180); // +
                            rotateX.setAngle(
                                    clamp(
                                            (((rotateX.getAngle() - direction * mouseDeltaY * modifier) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180),
                                            -60,
                                            60
                                    )
                            ); // -
                        }
                    }
                    updateLabels();
                }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Does the `SubScene` have focus?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX onKeyPressed event not being handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332190/javafx-onkeypressed-event-not-being-handled)

Comment: log.info("key={}", key.getCharacter()); This do anything?

Comment: Slaw, When I tested it, I click on the subscene moved the subscene around with the mouse (uses the above mouse events) and I tried hitting keys to see if they were logged. So I believe it has focus, in case that isn't meaningful

Comment: Lucifer, the keypresses isn't triggered at all so that specific change doesn't do anything.

Comment: The annoying thing is that I had mouse and key events working for a much more primitive version of the application 6 months ago. I just can't get the key press events to be recognized by the more modern version :)

Comment: ok, I figured how to make this work in a way that work for me. Answer below

Comment: Mouse events are delivered to nodes even if they don't have focus. Key events are only delivered to nodes which _have_ focus. The functionality that clicking on nodes gives them focus is not a feature of nodes; in other words, controls that have that functionality have manually implemented it in their behavior classes. You should call `requestFocus()` on the `SubScene` at some point in your program (e.g. at the start, if nothing else can ever grab the focus, or whenever you click on the `SubScene`).

Comment: Slaw, wrt to your latest comment. That is what I added to get it to work. See answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I just wanted to give a little more background information (mostly in response to your previous comments). Also, note that if you want me to be notified of a reply then you have to prefix my username with @ (e.g. @Slaw) unless one of us is the questioner/answerer and the other is the _only_ commenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the question above. I played around with things and found an answer that seems to work. I don't like it much but it works so...

I added one line to the below code "subScene.requestFocus();" This forces the focus and makes it work.

```
 subScene.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
                    mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                    mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                    mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
                    mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
                    subScene.requestFocus();
                }
        );
```

Comment: good that you don't like - it's brittle ;) You might try an eventFilter - depends on your context, providing a [mcve] demonstrating the problem might help to get more help <g>

Comment: yeah, exactly. It works, but I don't like it. I tried an event filter and it didn't catch the events.  The entire application is meant to load GAIA DR2/3 databases and present 3D models of the the stars in real space (distance and such). It's for science fiction writers so that can build realistic hard science descriptions of stellar systems. It would take quite a bit to build a minimal version. I guess the problem is how to give it focus. clicking on the screen gives it focus for key press events to work.  Thanks ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm not sure I agree this is brittle. If the application has other 2D controls then it makes sense to me that the user would have to explicitly focus the 3D sub-scene before they could interact with it via the keyboard. Though perhaps certain actions (e.g. start of program, finished loading of new data, etc.) should automatically focus the 3D sub-scene.

Comment: @Slaw _it makes sense to me that the user would have to explicitly focus_ basically agreed - but doing so in a mouse handler requires an interaction by mouse _before_ the interaction by keyboard is working. That's at least unintuitive and a violation of basic UX guidelines. My guess is that there is something wrong, either in usage or in the framework. Agree with _certain actions (e.g. start of program, finished loading of new data, etc.) should automatically focus_ :)

Comment: good points, but how to get the focus so that key events would work. Seems like we are in a chicken and egg issue.

Comment: not necessarily: there might be options, depending on context .. but .. back to the last sentence of my first comment ;)

Comment: @kleopatra, will see what I can do. might be a while. This is an open source project and I am getting ready to provide a beta for a number of well-known science fiction writers to play around with it. I have 7 minor issues to finish before it's releasable. They will probably have a bunch of "change this, change that" requests.

Comment: curious: which project, can you pass a link, shouldn't be a problem for open source :)

Comment: I am a spring boot dev. I learned javafx by doing it. Apologies for the crappy javafx code.  link is https://github.com/ljramones/trips.  If anyone competent wants to contrib, they are very are very welcome. The project came about from a group of science fiction writers wanting a way to show stellar relationships for their novels.